# Combine 2 numbers in excel in specific number format

Tags: excel, formatting, numbers, concatenation

I want to combine 2 numbers in separate columns in excel and have them output in a third column in a specific format.

For example, column 1 and column 2 both have values of 50 in them, formatted as number.  In column 3 I want to combine these values and have excel display them as 50.50.

Normally I'd just use concatenate, but I'm told this treats the data as a string and it doesn't seem to work later on when I want to display the value 50.50 in a pivot table.

Sorry if that's not 100% clear, but then that kind of sums up my knowledge of pivot tables/excel...  Any hints, tips or pointers would be great.

UPDATE:  Someone elsewhere has just solved this for me - if I use `C = A + (B / 100)` that seems to work fine for both the merge and the pivot table.  Also updates if either source value is changed and still appears as intended.

Answer (score 0):

A + B / 100 only works if your second number is exactly inbetween 10.00 and 99.00.
  For numbers of dynamic length, you could use

```
=A1+A2/(10^IFERROR((SEARCH(".",A2)-1),LEN(A2)))
```

Note that systems that don't use "." as a decimal seperator have to adapt the formula.